# XML Tags for layouts in Android

Tags: android, xml

I'm just starting out with Android development and am not too familiar with XML tags, particularly the closing ones. What is the difference between

```
<SomeWidget
    android:property1="foo"
    android:property2="bar"/>
```

and

```
<SomeWidget>
    android:property1="foo"
    android:property2="bar"
</SomeWidget>
```

specifically for things like buttons and layouts etc.?

Comment: use the first if the entire xml element can be defined in one chunk, use the second if an xml element has children-- for example, use the first one for `Button` but the second for `LinearLayout` or `ScrollView`

Comment: @Neoh They are not the same from an XML point of view.  android:property1="foo" is an attribute in the first example and text/string data in the second parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the second example when there is embedded XML information, i.e. when the layout serves as a parent to other widgets/layouts. e.g:

`<SomeLayout android:prop = value>

 <InnerLayout android:prop = value2/>

</SomeLayout>`

The first example is sufficient (although both styles will work) when it is a leaf in the XML structure (InnerLayout).

Answer (score 0):

The two formats are essentially the same.

You can use either, and they are identical in regards to how the system interprets XML.

For what it is worth, the first way is used by the framework when it applies auto-formatting (ie. using the Cmd-Shift-F key).

Bottom line, you can use whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Properties are set using attributes, and in XML attributes are in opening tag, between `<` and `>`. If opening and closing tags do not contain any child tags inside them, then closing tag can be dropped and opening tag is ended with `/`.